# WordPress automaticly adds styles to 'html' tag

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

When i logged in as admin on WordPress, it adds this style="height: (height of content);" in html tag, like below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 695px;">
```

Can i turn it off? Where?
By the way, when i visit site as a guest, html tag looks like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 695px;">
```

Comment: The `<html>` tag is not required in HTML5.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't do this, it's your template that does this. Check the javascript file of your template!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty strange. I'm not sure I've ever seen WP do that before. But you can override inline styles with an `!important` declaration. So this should give you an auto height:

```
html {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Or, you can use javascript to remove the style attribute:

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
htmlElement.removeAttribute("style")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WordPress, but if you add this to your stylesheet, it will at least override that inline style with `height`'s default value of `auto`:

```
 html { height: auto !important; }
```